# CUDA compute capabilities from card name

Tags: cuda, nvidia, video-card

Is there a way to discover CUDA **sm_xx** version by card name?

My specific problem is: I have a CUDA application which requires **SM_12** or higher and I have a customer who has a **Quadro Q5000**. How can I discover whether that card has SM_12 or higher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following resources are reasonably accurate:

[NVIDIA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus)

[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA)

Q5000 is a sm_20 device (compute capability 2.0)

Google is your friend.